# apache htaccess Header Set only working for static files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a php application that directs all urls that don't point to a static file to index.php (configured in `.htaccess`)

I added the following configuration to add a header to all requests in my `.htaccess` file, but the header is only applied to urls that go to static files.

```
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

What could prevent the header from being applied to index.php?

Comment: where/how are you applying this? a directive by itself is pretty much useless without any context. e.g. if that's tatooed to your forehead, then yeah, why would you expect apache to be reading your tatoo?

Comment: updated the question to include that the configuration I've placed is in .htaccess

Comment: which still doesn't help. if you have, that directive in an `<if>` block or something...

Comment: I don't have it in any if block. The header is being applied to my js, css, and image files...just not the urls that are rewritten to index.php

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that the mod_header module wasn't working with php fastcgi. It started working after switching to mod_php.