# htaccess header not applied on http file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I want to add HTTP response header using htaccess file, but it is not applied on the main file while all resources like css and img files gets that header. My htaccess file looks like this:

```html
RewriteEngine On
Header always set test-header "value"
    
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myurl.goes.here/$1 [R,L]
    
</IfModule>
```

I tried to move "Header set" line across different places in my file but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue was because of using php fastcgi like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597918/apache-htaccess-header-set-only-working-for-static-files). I'm using managed service so unable to change configuration, but adding headers in PHP code by using [header command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) worked fine.